# Outputting element from two-dimensional array from separate class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to output the second element from a two-dimensional array from one class to a TableViewController. I've tried a couple things, such as data.reduce into:, with no luck. The FirstViewController is supposed to be populated with the three genres "Action, Suspense and Romance", which can then be clicked on to show all the movies that belong to that genre.

**First Class:**

```
     import Foundation

        protocol MovieModelDelegate: class {
           func didRecieveDataUpdate(data: [[String]])
        }

        class MovieModel {

           weak var delegate: MovieModelDelegate?

           var genreArray: [String] = []
           let data: [[String]] = [
              ["Avatar", "Action"],
              ["Limitless", "Suspense"],
              ["Die Hard", "Action"],
              ["The Avengers", "Action"],
              ["The Notebook", "Romance"],
              ["Lakehouse", "Romance"],
              ["Gone Girl", "Suspense"],
              ["Deadpool", "Action"],
              ["Passengers", "Suspense"],
              ["Inception", "Suspense"],
              ["Mission Impossible", "Action"]
         ]

          func requestData() {
             let movie: [[String]] = data
             delegate?.didRecieveDataUpdate(data: movie)
          }
       }


**TableView Class:**


    class FirstTableView: UITableViewController, MovieModelDelegate {

       var model = MovieModel()
       var selectedGenre: String = ""

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          model.delegate = self
          model.requestData()
       }

       override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          return 1
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return model.genreArray.count
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GenreCells", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
          cell.genreLabel?.text = model.genreArray[indexPath.item]
          return cell
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          selectedGenre = model.data[indexPath.row]
          selectedGenre = ""
          for indexPath in model.data{
              if indexPath[1] == selectedGenre{
                  selectedGenre.append(indexPath[0])
              }
          }
      }

      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
          if (segue.identifier == "pushToMovies") {
              if let VC = segue.destination as? FilteredSelection {
                  VC.selectedMovies = [selectedGenre]
              }
          }
      }

      func didRecieveDataUpdate(data: [[String]]) {
      }

      deinit{
      }
  }
```

Comment: Just curious. Why don't you use a dictionary instead?
Something like, {"action" :[ all movie names of action type ], "suspense" : [ ... ] ,... }
By doing this, when the user selects a genre , say, 'action', then you just add that to your list that you want to send to the next VC.
Something like,  list.append(dictionary.object(forKey : "action"))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` to get all Genres without to have duplicates.

1. I recognized you want to display the genres in your `TableView` with `model.genreArray` but your `genreArray` is always empty because you never append data to it.
2. The second thing I recoginzed: In your `TableViewController` you
   implemented the `didReciveDataUpdate` function, but you didnt do
   anything with it.

## First Class:

```
 import Foundation
    protocol MovieModelDelegate: class {
       func didRecieveDataUpdate(data: [[String]])
    }

    class MovieModel {

       weak var delegate: MovieModelDelegate?


       let data: [[String]] = [
          ["Avatar", "Action"],
          ["Limitless", "Suspense"],
          ["Die Hard", "Action"],
          ["The Avengers", "Action"],
          ["The Notebook", "Romance"],
          ["Lakehouse", "Romance"],
          ["Gone Girl", "Suspense"],
          ["Deadpool", "Action"],
          ["Passengers", "Suspense"],
          ["Inception", "Suspense"],
          ["Mission Impossible", "Action"]
     ]

     private var genres = [String]()

     public init() {
     for dataSet in data {
        self.genres.append(dataSet[1])
     }

     //this will generate a array with only uniqe genres
     var genreArray = Array(Set(self.genres))

     }

      func requestData() {
         let movie: [[String]] = data
         delegate?.didRecieveDataUpdate(data: movie)
      }
   }
```

## FirstTableView Class:

(*view didReciveDataUpdate function*)

```
 class FirstTableView: UITableViewController, MovieModelDelegate {

   var model = MovieModel()
   var selectedGenre: String = ""

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      model.delegate = self
      model.requestData()
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return model.genreArray.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GenreCells", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
      cell.genreLabel?.text = model.genreArray[indexPath.row]
      return cell
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     //To get the Genre
      selectedGenre = model.data[indexPath.row][1]

      for indexPath in model.data{
          if indexPath[1] == selectedGenre{
              selectedGenre.append(indexPath[0])
          }
      }
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if (segue.identifier == "pushToMovies") {
          if let VC = segue.destination as? FilteredSelection {
              VC.selectedMovies = [selectedGenre]
          }
      }
  }

  func didRecieveDataUpdate(data: [[String]]) {
     //=================here you need to update your tableView===================
  }

  deinit{
  }
```

}

Comment: I get two errors when I use this code. one for var genreArray = Array(Set(genres)) "Cannot use instance member 'genres' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" and the other error for selectedGenre = model.data[indexPath.row] "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'"

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of the errors. However, Nothing loads in the tableview.

Comment: Can you show your code in the `didReciveDataUpdate(data: [[String]])` function?

Comment: I have not filled that part yet. I have never used that function before.

Comment: So why you have it when you dont use it?

Comment: I picked it up from someone else. If it isn't necessary, then I I won't use it.

Comment: Maybe I found why nothing shows in your table view: in your ` tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function change the line `cell.genreLabel?.text = model.genreArray[indexPath.item]` => insted of `indexPath.item` use `indexPath.row` I hope after that you can see anything in your tableView

Comment: I am not seeing any difference with that change.

Comment: The last possibility is that your custom TableViewCell dont work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the data into a form that can then be indexed by a tableview. I would change it into a dictionary using the following code.

```
let genreDictionary = data.reduce(into: [:]) { d, element in
    d[element[1], default: []].append(element[0])
}
```

This will create the following Dictionary

```
["Suspense": ["Limitless", "Gone Girl", "Passengers", "Inception"], 
 "Romance": ["The Notebook", "Lakehouse"], 
 "Action": ["Avatar", "Die Hard", "The Avengers", "Deadpool", "Mission Impossible"]]
```

Then in your tableview functions you use the dictionary as follows

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return model.genreDictionary.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GenreCells", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
      let d = model.genreDictionary
      cell.genreLabel?.text = d[d.keys.index(d.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)].key
      return cell
   }
```

When you need the array of films for a certain tableview row you can use the following

```
let d = model.genreDictionary
let arrayOfFilms = d[d.keys.index(d.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)].value
```